# How to automate the process of deploying a servlet using Eclipse and Tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm developing a web service application, and although the services are operating like they should, I think the time I take to develop, test and fix my code are being wasted. Here is what I'm doing:

1. I have a normal java project in Eclipse, where I have all my code
   for the web service. I added a javax.servlet.jar library to the
   build path, and receive the requests using
   `service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)` from
   `HttpServlet`, and print the result in JSON format. I use the main
   method to test and fix some part of the code
2. When I feel confident that my code is fine I navigate to the
   workspace, copy all the class files, stop tomcat server, delete the
   old files deployed at web-inf, paste the new class files and start
   the tomcat server.

**My question is:** Is there a faster way to do (ii) so I can iterate faster in the process of programming/testing/fixing? I have seen that I can achieve what I want using Dynamic Web Project, but I fear it might be difficult to migrate and cause problems with SVN.

Thank you!

Comment: are you using maven to build the project? if yes than use maven tomcat/jetty plugin and start that process in debug mode.           or   start your tomcat in debug mode and provide and connect your tomcat with JPDA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a lot of ways to achieve that.

You could for example configure your java project to output `.class` files in to the `WEB-INF\classes` of the `docbase` of the web-app hosting your web services.

```
right click on your project > Build path > configure build path > source
```

an then browse to the folder you want.

Start your tomcat from eclipse using [tomcat eclipse plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html). It starts it by default in debug mode.

Or you could add - at least - the facet `Dynamic Web Module` to your project under

```
right click on your project > properties > Project Facets
```

and choose tomcat as runtime (click on new... to create a new one if not already done). In that case you can remove the extra jar you have for `HttpServlet` because the new runtime adds all the libs you need. After doing that you can just run project on the server using

```
right click > run as > run on server
```

and then choosing a server on which you want your project to run on. You can run in debug mode using `debug as` instead of `run as`.

In both cases you can take advantage from the Hot [swap abilities of the jvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jpda/enhancements.html#hotswap). The server will only need to be restarted if it is not possible to hot swap the code, i.e whe you change a method signature or add some fields to class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I liked the second approach, and I'm trying to work on that. But I'm getting an error saying [Runtime "Apache Tomcat v7.0" is invalid](http://i69.photobucket.com/albums/i47/Alverine/tomcaterror_zpsfeaa620c.jpg). I also can't point to where my catalina_home is. Do you know what is the problem? I have all this facets from Jboss Tools.

Comment: @MarcoAltran, maybe you haven't already created one, please check under `window > preferences > Server > Runtime Environments` and add one there, it's a straight forward wizard. or just edit an existing one a try to fix it. probably the tomcat installation directory is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Sysdeo tomcat plugin for eclipse. http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html it lets you point tomcat to use your target directory in your project as a webapp. Allowing for hotswap code replacement and easy start, stop and restart. Start by downloading the plugin from the link above then making a file `ROOT.xml` in this sub directory of your tomcat instillation `conf\Catalina\localhost\`

The content would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="C:\workdir\myapp\src\main\webapp" path="/"/>
```

Then you can add that projects library dependencies to tomcats classpath as well by going to eclipse->properties->tomcat->advanced also eclipse->properties->tomcat->source path and checking the box next to your project